# mvc3 client side validation not firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, client-side

(UPDATED 09/14/2012)

This is my controller:

```
<HttpPost()> _
Public Function Login(ByVal viewmodel As LoginViewModel) As ActionResult
    Dim result As New LoginResponse()
    Try
        Dim objUserCredentialsType As UserCredentialsType = UserProfileType.Login(viewmodel.UserName, viewmodel.Password, 0, CStr(AppSettings("softwareLicense")))
        'store user credentials in session
        HttpContext.Session.Add("_CurrentUserCredentials", objUserCredentialsType)
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(viewmodel.UserName, viewmodel.RememberMe)
        result.Status = "Success"
        result.ReturnUrl = "~/Account/Welcome"
        Return Json(result)
    Catch ex As Exception
        result.Status = "Failed"
        result.Errors.Add(ExceptionWrapper.Wrap(ex).ExceptionMessage())
        Return Json(result)
    End Try
End Function

Public Class LoginResponse
    Public Property Status() As String
        Get
            Return m_Status
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Status = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Status As String
    Public Property Errors() As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return m_Errors
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of String))
            m_Errors = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Errors As List(Of String)
    Public Property ReturnUrl() As String
        Get
            Return m_ReturnUrl
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_ReturnUrl = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ReturnUrl As String
    Public Sub New()
        Errors = New List(Of String)()
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is my view:

```
<section id="login">
    <div id="login-form-container" class="span6">
        @Using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account", Nothing, New AjaxOptions With {.HttpMethod = "post", .OnBegin = "LoginFormAjaxValidate"}, New With {.id = "login-form"}))
            @<fieldset>
                <legend>Log in to your account now</legend>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12">
                        @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.UserName)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.UserName, New With {.class = "span12", .placeholder = "Username"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.UserName)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <label for="Password">Your password</label>
                        @Html.PasswordFor(Function(m) m.Password, New With {.class = "span12", .placeholder = "Password", .type = "password"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.Password)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <label for="RememberMe" class="checkbox clearfix">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(Function(m) m.RememberMe)
                            Remember me next time I visit
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button id="login-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary input-small" value="submit">Log in</button>
            </fieldset>
        End Using                                  
    </div>
</section>
```

This is the script at the bottom of the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function LoginFormAjaxValidate() {
    $("#login-form").serialize(), function (r) {
        if (r.Status == "Success") {
            top.location.href = "@Url.Content("~/Account/Welcome")";
        }
        else {
            //Lets get the Errors from our JSON
            $.each(r.Errors, function (index, item) {
                alert(r.item);
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but it looks like you're manually posting the form data rather than submitting the form through the browser.  Is it possible that those are different, and by posting the data manually, you are bypassing the submit action of the form, thus bypassing the client-side validation?  Would you need to manually invoke client-side validation with the AJAX-based post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
function ajaxValidate() {
   return $('my-login-form').validate().form();
}
```

and change your form declaration to this:

```
@Using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account", Nothing,
    New AjaxOptions With {.HttpMethod = "post",
    .UpdateTargetId = "login-form",
    .OnBegin="ajaxValidate",
    .OnSuccess = "LoginFormSuccess"},
    New With { .id = "my-login-form"}))
```

Also I would rename your div id="login-form" to id="login-form-container" for bravity. If you choose to rename that div, then just update "my-login-form" to "login-form" in cs and js code.

Comment: This whole issue began as I had originally wired everything up correctly to post the form via ajax and return the server side errors without full postback...so my controller returns the json result for both success and failure...what I'm still confused about is what in this scenario is the controller responsible for and what should the javascript be handling? if you look at the controller code, you can see that at no point am I redirecting...just returning the JSON results...is that the correct way to handle that or should everything be handled with javascript as I had before?

Comment: Your controller should be responsible for handling success, error AND validation error states. Validation error state is optional since most basic validation can be done via javascript and handled in ajaxValidate function as I suggested. You should add a redirect url to your success result, and handle redirection in javascript, using your success function, LoginFormSuccess.

Comment: Can you please look at my controller code and specify what exactly I'm doing wrong? You say that Controller should be handling error states - my issue is the relationship between the controller and javascript. I've updated the code AGAIN - using that code could you PLEASE let me know where I'm tripping up? The success, begin, and fail functions are still not firing...not sure why.  I tried simplifying each function, but it never gets there.  The controller is overriding the javascript and just redirecting to new page with JSON result.

Comment: sure. Can you add you model code? FYI. Each model property must be decorated with a validation attribute.

Comment: Yep, I posted the LoginViewModel above...thank you again for the response and help. Pretty sure the issue is the "Return Json(result)" line in the controller, but I don't get why that is overriding any javascript functionality?

Comment: make sure to add this to your view: <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>    Once you added it you can catch your json return this way: top.location.href =result.ReturnUrl; in LoginFormSuccess

Comment: so embarrassing - that was it.  last question, though...when I submit the form, do I need to use an updatetargetid? what's the purpose? right now, when I do submit the actual form element is disappearing when the markup is redrawn.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16664/discussion-between-michael-and-nuhusky2003)

Comment: UpdatetargetId is used for displaying any content returned from action, ex. ContentResult or PartialView . It should be inside your form. In your case you don't need it.

Comment: I was trying to add logic to handle the json result, but can't seem to reference it....do I need to manually serialize the form?

Answer (score 2):

I don't do VB but here is what my view model and ActionMethod look like in c#

Make sure you are properly including the following javascript files

jquery.unobtrusive-ajax
jquery.validate.unobtrusive
jquery.validate

Also check the annotations on your view model.  View the rendered html and make sure you see the data validation attributes being rendered.

EX OUTPUT SHOULD LOOK SOMETHING LIKE THIS:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-email="Invalid E-Mail Address" data-val-required="E-Mail Address is required" id="UserName" name="UserName" type="email" value="" />&nbsp;<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="UserName" data-valmsg-replace="true">
```

Where are the rest of your Ajax Options? All I see are the call backs??

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SignIn", "Account", null, new AjaxOptions
                                                      {
                                                          HttpMethod = "post",
                                                          UpdateTargetId = "ajax-sign-in",
                                                          InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                                          OnSuccess = "Success"
                                                      }, new {@autocomplete = "on"}))
{
 YOUR FORM HTML...... HERE
}



public class AccountSignInViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "E-Mail Address")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "E-Mail Address is required")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid E-Mail Address")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a password")]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Remember My Login?")]
    public bool RemeberLogin { get; set; }
}

 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SignIn(AccountSignInViewModel accountSignInViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // DO SOME AUTHENTICATION STUFFS
        }
        return PartialView("_LocalSignIn");
    }
```

Comment: sorry but how/where are you retrieving the business model/server side errors? i've edited my code again and can get the json results, but am still confused as to how to properly wire everything up so that if there's an exception, i want to grab the results via json and display those. if it's successful then redirect to another page.

Comment: do I still need to wire up the javascript to handle the postback and server side error display?

Comment: Yes you do. The unobtrusive validation will be handled before all but one of your callbacks.

Comment: then now i'm truly confused...at first I was told not to wire up the javascript to handle the form submission because that's why the client side stuff wasn't firing...now I'm told I do need to wire it up - how can they both coexist without breaking either the client side stuff or server side stuff?

Comment: Your Ajax.BeginForm is responsible for actually submitting the form. Validation will happen before that event anyway. Client side validation and server side validation in your controller have absolutely no ties to each other. One is on the server and the other is on the client.

Comment: Please post your updated code and your viewmodel so we can take a look at it

Comment: You also need to call the validation again in your view that gets returned

Comment: crazy - updated my original code above...part of my issue now is that I don't know how to fetch the json result from the controller in the javascript...when I manually wired it up, I was just serializing the form to retrieve those values...now, the serialize screws everything up

Comment: I don't see where you are serializing the LoginResponse. You have to return valid JSON

Comment: Client side works fine obviously - required fields stop form from submitting...the issue now is retrieving json result from controller to be handled in the view javascript...so I guess the answer to your question is basically a no and I can only assume it's my view javascript that's the issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16709/discussion-between-crazycoderz-and-michael)

Answer (score 1):

By sending the form manually on the submit function, you aren't allowing the validator to kick in.  You therefore bypass the validator and all its unobtrusive niceties.

If you want to do an ajax postback, use the Ajax.BeginForm helper instead.  It will provide you with the hooks you need to do the block out of the form while it loads and also have an onsuccess callback to do the redirect.

If there is no javascript enabled, then it will revert to a normal form and the action method will be called and your controller can handle that and return appropriately.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function formSuccess(result, status, xhr) {
        // result has the response object
    }

    function formFailed(xhr, status, result) {
        // params are flipped in the error handler, not sure why
    }

    function formBegin(object, xhr) {
        // return false in here if you don't want to submit the form
        return true;
    }
</script>
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new {id = 1 /* route values */ },new AjaxOptions{ OnBegin = "formBegin", OnSuccess = "formSuccess", OnFailure = "formFailure"}, new { @class="form"/* html attributes */ } ))
{
    @*
        put your form bits in here
     *@
}
```

Si

Comment: tried using the ajax.beginform with no success....not sure of what to correctly supply in the parameters (never used this before), but using just default values doesn't help - what would your code look like?  I'm just supplying the name of the action, controller, and then entering "nothing" for the other 3 parameters

Comment: Updated with a sample that shows how I wire up an ajax.beginform, HTH

Comment: everything compiles, and the client-side stuff is working now, but I can't seem to get the onsuccess and onfailure events to fire properly...I updated the code to match what I have...the alerts aren't firing or preventing the form from being submitted.

Comment: The OnSuccess and OnFailure handlers are fired on the status code that is returned from the controller.  When something errors, return a status code that reflects it.  Ie. 400 for validation errors in the model state and 500 for exceptions etc.  As for the OnBegin, if you dont want to the form to submit, return false straight away, i.e. not waiting on some async process to complete.

Comment: appreciate the response...but the request doesn't seem to be submitting asynchronously...it's returning false for HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest().  not sure i follow where i'm slipping up.

Comment: that flag is controlled by a query string parameter I believe, if you monitor the traffic in fiddler do you see the request tagged with something like requested-by =xmlhttprequest?

Comment: My bad, it is a header. X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest.  If you open the site in chome, can you use the console to submit the form manually?